# Autowire a single argument in a constructor

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

In a constructor with 2 arguments, I want to explicitly wire one and autowire the other.

Something like:

```
public Obj(Interface arg, Interface arg2) {
    // stuff
}
```

And in the bean definition:

```
<bean id="objImpl" class="com.work.Obj">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="interfaceImpl"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" autowire-this-somehow/>
</bean>
```

Does anyone know of a way ?

Comment: What stopping you from using ref?

Comment: And why not autowiring the other one, as well?

Comment: I don't want want to get into this in this question as it will be too long. So I'll just say because legacy project code, because bad design, bla bla bla ...

Comment: What I need currently is a dirty ugly hack, this is what I'm asking for :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<bean id="objImpl" class="com.work.Obj" autowire="constructor">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="interfaceImpl"/>
</bean>
```

Here, you have specified that bean of type `com.work.Obj` should created using constructor autowiring. If you specify any constructor arg, then it overrides autowired arg. So index 0 is explicitly provided. Other args which are not explicitly provided will be autowired by type.

**Caution**: constructor autowiring has the same limitation as `byType` - Spring won't attempt to guess which bean to autowire when it finds multiple beans that match a constructor arg. Further, if the class has multiple constructors, any of which can be satisfied by autowiring, then Spring won't attempt to guess which constructor to use. You will get an exception in this case.

**EDIT:** For this to work, other beans of type `Interface` (constructor arg type) except the one that needs to be autowired, should be marked with `autowire-candidate=false`

Example:

```
<bean id="impl1" class="stackoverflow.SomeImpl" autowire-candidate="false"/>
<bean id="impl2" class="stackoverflow.SomeImpl"/>

<bean id="obj" class="stackoverflow.Obj" autowire="constructor">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="impl1"/>
</bean>
```

And Obj class:

```
package stackoverflow;

public class Obj {
    public Obj(SomeInterface i1, SomeInterface i2){
        System.out.println("i1" + i1);
        System.out.println("i2" + i2);
    }
}
```

Here `SomeImpl implements SomeInterface`. On running `impl2` bean is autowired in the second constructor arg `i2`. The first arg is manually provided in Spring config.

Comment: And how do you autowire the second argument, when there are two possible values for it: `interfaceImpl` (the value already used for first argument) and `someOtherInterfaceImpl`?

Comment: @AndreiStefan as I mentioned `Spring won't attempt to guess which bean to autowire when it finds multiple beans that match a constructor arg` You will get an exception. If you want, you can set `autowire-candidate=false` on those beans that you are sure that you don't want autowired.

Comment: I know, that's why I was asking to point out that the solution you offered isn't actually a solution. With your code, there will be an exception.

Comment: @AndreiStefan as I mentioned in my above comment - all beans of type `Interface` except the one that needs to be autowired should be marked with `autowire-candidate="false"` so that Spring can select only one bean as the suitable candidate. I know, it is messy, but that is what is asked by Simeon :)